# send_keys isn't identified although I imported selenium and keys

Tags: python, selenium

I imported the keys but for some reason it isn't being identified. Here is my code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("..\Library\chromedriver.exe")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.find_elements_by_name("q").sendKeys("Test")
driver.find_elements_by_name("btnK").click()
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: In Python its `send_keys`

Comment: You need to be more specific. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: By the way, `find_elements_by_name` return list you can use `send_keys` on it. You are looking for `find_element_by_name`

Comment: Also there is no need in `Keys` if you want to use `send_keys` method

Answer (score 4):

You are using `find_elements_by_name()` which returns a list of elements and not compatible with `send_keys()` function. You have to use `find_element_by_name()` instead.

The correct line would be

```
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Test")
driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good answer Smashguy, as my with append your answer

Answer (score 0):

The Difference Between FindElement And FindElements Methods.

- **FindElement()**

You can use this command to access any single element on the web page.
It returns the object of the first matching element of the specified locator.
It throws a NoSuchElementException exception when it fails to find If the element.
Its syntax is as follows.

```
username = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
```

- **FindElements()**

It gives back the whole list of all the elements matching the specified locator.
If the element doesn’t exist or not available on the page then, the return value will be an empty list.
Its syntax is as follows.

```
searchresults_text = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'Locator value')
```

and yes @SmashGuy is correct

```
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Hello Google")
```